# How to TEST(D) DATE if have format yyyy/mm/dd in RPGLE?

Tags: date, rpgle

How to test char date in format yyyy/mm/dd ?

I try to use :

```
*YMD      TEST(D)       DATE            80
```

I want to test this 2021/15/30 date because I want to make sure the date is validated but seems like it doesn't work even if I test the right Date like 2021/06/01. What should I do?

I also try this :

```
          Eval    DT = %CHAR(%DATE(DATE:*YMD/))    
*YMD      TEST(DE)       DT           
          IF NOT %ERROR()

          Move    DT      DATE
          Write   Currec

          Endif
```

I enter 2021/06/01 as input but got this error instead :

[image: error]

What should I do?

Comment: This may help
https://www.mcpressonline.com/forum/forum/programming/rpg/12596-validate-iso-date-in-free

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RPG doesn't support the YYYY/MM/DD format. You can use %XLATE to change the / to - and then use the *ISO format.

```
          EVAL    DATE = %XLATE('/' : '-' : DATE)
*ISO      TEST(DE)       DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

I avoid fixed format code so I haven't confirmed if this is correct or not but I believe you should be using either `*YYMD` or `*ISO` instead of `*YMD` for this particular test given the format you want to check.  Relevant links:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=80-datfmt-date-format-keyword-physical-logical-files
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.1?topic=codes-test-test-datetimetimestamp

Comment: I do not think *ISO will work with the '/' date separator.  Might have to first replace '/' with '-'.